# Deactivating jQuery UI tabs() function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, materialize

I have this massive legacy code application and I need to modify as little as possible because it's untested and there is no clear way to determine when a JS library is being depended on.

The section I'm working with uses [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/) and [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/). After a couple of hours debugging why the basic example of tabs from materialize wouldn't work, it seems it's because of jQueryUI's `tabs()` method. Apparently both library has exactly the same public API (even though Materialize depends on jQuery, one would think this wouldn't happen but who am I to judge right :)?)

Is there a way I can deactivate jQuery UI `tabs()` function, so that it'd call Materialize's one?

**If possible**, I'd like a solution that doesn't require loading the libraries in a specific order, because this legacy app has a rather particular way of loading them and that'd be problematic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: create your custom version excluding Tabs : [Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

Comment: Can't it be like proxied it or something instead? This project has no build task or anything. Any project-wide changes are prone to break something.